# Kotlin "^=" operator

Tags: kotlin

Is there Kotlin analogue to Java `^=` (xor and assign) operator?

For instance, in Java we can simply write

```
a ^= b
// a = a ^ b
```

It looks like in Kotlin we need to assign value explicitly

```
a = a xor b
```

Is it possible to avoid duplication of variable `a` in Kotlin code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Kotlin exponent operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50270435/what-is-the-kotlin-exponent-operator)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50270435/what-is-the-kotlin-exponent-operator

Comment: No, unfortunately there is no version of Java’s ^= or |=.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike C, C++ and Java, Kotlin doesn’t have bitwise operators like |(bitwise-or), &(bitwise-and), ^(bitwise-xor), << (signed left shift), >>(signed right shift) etc.

For performing bitwise operations, Kotlin provides following methods that work for Int and Long types -

- shl - signed shift left (equivalent of << operator)
- shr - signed shift right (equivalent of >> operator)
- ushr - unsigned shift right (equivalent of >>> operator)
- and - bitwise and (equivalent of & operator)
- or - bitwise or (equivalent of | operator)
- xor - bitwise xor (equivalent of ^ operator)
- inv - bitwise complement (equivalent of ~ operator)